# setting local time of server

Tags: php

I think the penny is starting to drop, but I cant find a clear definition. Heres my question :

I am UK based but my server is GMT -7. I've been adding database enteries by simply setting my db field "Time" (which is a timestamp) to NOW(). This appears to be adding the local time of my server which is in Phoenix USA (-7 hrs behind me).

Should I be using  date_defaault_timezone_set and _get, set to my appropriate timezones, to handle the differences in my location (in other words I have to SPECIFICALLY handle the timezone in and out of my database).

So for example, accessing my db online I set my config to America/Phoenix, but if I COPY my db onto my localhost running on UK I need to set the timezone to Europe/London. ONLY THEN will i be correctly writing timestamps into my db.

is that right?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're not working with absolute times (i.e. timestamps), you shouldn't save them in that format in the database. Use `datetime` fields instead.

Comment: Why should I use datetime fields?

Comment: Because then they won't be affected by timezones. If you save "2011-10-11 10:00:00", it always means 10 AM. If you save 1318320841, its an absolute time that's represented as different times around the world in different timezones.

Comment: Good point,but thinking forward, won't I need timezones if want to roll my services out past the UK?

Comment: Only if the app needs to compare times that are given in different timezones.

Answer (score 0):

You can set timezone for MySQL at once after connection:

```
mysql_query("SET time_zone = your_timezone");
```

Or you can set time zone for your php setting:

```
date_default_timezone_set('your_timezone');
```

Comment: Will the php cover both? ( seeing as I'm calling NOW() from a php expression)

Comment: I think use use 'NOW()' in sql query, right? Because php does not have this function.